Are "many" members of the Jamaat-ul-Mujahideen Bangladesh also members of the student wing of the Jamaat-e-Islami?
Canadian Immigration quotes:

An article in Power Politics indicates that "many" members of the JMB are also members of Islami Chhatra Chibir, which is the student wing of the Jamaat-e-Islami, a Bangladeshi political party (1 Oct. 2016). Corroborating information could not be found among the sources consulted by the Research Directorate within the time constraints of this Response.

According to Wikipedia, JMB (Jamaat-ul-Mujahideen Bangladesh) is considered a terrorist organization by the UK and a few other countries. Are "many" of its members also members of the student wing of the Jamaat-e-Islami political party of Bangladesh?

According to one CTC article, JMB had 'thousands' of members, or at least sympathisers, so the intersection with ICS having "many" individuals would mean hundreds, at least, I suppose, belonging to both.
